# ServiceNow : Clone request feature doesn't copy all request fields

Tags: servicenow

I need a help to understand cloning feature.

I create a request I select a company in the checkout process :

```
https://ibb.co/L9VjHjh
```

After checkout I clone my new request :

```
https://ibb.co/kyDPxqV
```

But I have a problem with the cloned request, the COMPANY field haven't been copied as you can see :

```
https://ibb.co/MkhQQ04
```

I think I need to modify the UI macro `sc_order_status_view_clone_checkout` but I'm not sure.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Does the cloned request have the "parent" field filled in with the initial one? i.e. does  REQ0010012 reference REQ0010011 anywhere?

Comment: hello, no parent field is empty!